# robot_pose_ekf publish rate?

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having trouble getting the robot_pose_ekf node running correctly.  I have a nav_msgs::Odometry topic from a GPS sensor publishing at 1Hz on the 'vo' topic and an sensor_msgs::Imu publishing at 20 Hz on the 'imu_data' topic.  However, over the course of a minute long run, the odom_combined topic is only publishing 5-6 messages.

The parameters I've used in the launch file are:

```
param name="output_frame" value="odom_combined"<br>
param name="freq" value="20.0"<br>
param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"<br>
param name="odom_used" value="false"<br>
param name="imu_used" value="true"<br>
param name="vo_used" value="true"<br>
```

My data is being published from a bag file.  Could this be an issue at all?  Why else might the ekf node not be publishing at the rate given by freq?

Thanks,
Josh

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36329/robot_pose_ekf-publish-rate?/) by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 971 on 2012-06-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2012-09-06**:
Thanks, for some reason, every time I read that wiki page I understood it to mean it would publish once just a single initial data point had been published on each sensor topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

since your gps is operating at 1 Hz, i think the maximum frequency with which you can publish is 1 Hz. This is because according to basic ekf, the predictor is updated as and when the data from the imu is available and then when the gps data is available, the values are corrected and then published.
I think this is reason why you can't publish at 20 Hz.

ATB!
(PS: I am not sure if my answer is right, but it is as per my limited knowledge...Please correct me if my answer is wrong)

---

Originally posted by [sethu chidam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2825/sethu-chidam/) with karma: 26 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you are right

here is the paragraph about timing on robot_pose_ekf 's [wiki](http://ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf)

Imagine the robot pose filter was last updated at time t_0. The node will not update the robot pose filter until at least one measurement of each sensor arrived with a timestamp later than t_0. When e.g. a message was received on the odom topic with timestamp t_1 > t_0, and on the imu_data topic with timestamp t_2 > t_1 > t_0, the filter will now update to the latest time at which information about all sensors is available, in this case to time t_1. The odom pose at t_1 is directly given, and the imu pose at t_1 is obtained by linear interpolation of the imu pose between t_0 and t_2. The robot pose filter is updated with the relative poses of the odom and imu, between t_0 and t_1.

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-07-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1